# Is there a website like Stack Overflow that specializes in code review?

Tags: discussion, review, site-recommendation

Is there a website like Stack Overflow that specializes in code review? I always have code that needs to be reviewed. Is there a specialized website for that?

Comment: Google Code has code review capabilities but I'm not sure if many people are willing to volunteer code reviewing other people's code. It's not fun most of the time.

Comment: I just love the structure and simplicity of SO. There are plenty of great sites in the StackExchange network and something like the abovesaid question will be an even more awesome addition.

Comment: I would find a spin-off of SO that does this an interesting idea, but those in real need of a code review would get flamed to death within minutes, so in the end, it probably wouldn't work very well quantity wise. Probably better to ask specific questions here.

Comment: SO has built policing into the system itself which is working out nicely here. Unhelpful comments or answers get downvoted almost always. Call it a mob-rule or whatever, but its working great here and I am guessing should be the same in a code review site in stackexchange. Plus the SO community has become quite adept at rooting out the gimmeh-the-code and do-mah-homework questions rather quickly without too much flaming.

Answer (score 24):

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions . Community is vibrant and growing